# No edit button on events in Apple Calendar with shared Google Calendar (iCal)

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar

I'm using google calendars with 2 different calendars on my account. I added the calendars to Apple Calendar via the Internet Accounts options.

All events turn up as expected in Apple Calendar but I cannot find an edit button to change an event.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no edit button...
Just double click on the event you want to edit, then, in the pop up, click the title, and now you’re able to edit the title, click on the other data to change that.

Comment: OMG! Useability can be too good / bad sometimes. Thanks a lot!